# Change checkbox background color on checkbox check and uncheck

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a checkbox inside a gridview and I want to change the backcolor of that checkbox on check and uncheck.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="checkboxAttendanceStatus" ClientIDMode="Static" BackColor="red" runat="server" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I used a jquery for the purpose but it's not working.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#checkboxAttendanceStatus').change(function () {
            alert('asdas');
            $("#checkboxAttendanceStatus").css("backcolor", "green");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Start by checking the ID's of the CheckBoxes in the actual HTML...

Comment: ID is correct. I have posted the html code too above.

Comment: Can you share the generated HTML?

Comment: Again, did you check the actual HTML that is being generated. Not the code  you see in the editor. If you did you will see that they are NOT the same.

Comment: Yes, I used ClientIDMode="Static". After doing that I am getting the alert message but just for the first entry of the grid view. And again, no color change at all.

Comment: use this `row.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Yellow;`

Comment: @user6594294 I don't want to do autopostback for every checkbox click.

Comment: @SuyashGupta is `alert('asdas');` working in your code

Comment: Yes, now with the help of @NnN, I am able to change the color also but only for the first entry of the grid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9qttjqvb/5/)

**HTML(sample):**

```
<div id="div">
    <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#chk').on('change', function(){
    if($('#chk').prop('checked'))
       $('#div').css('background', 'green');
     else
       $('#div').css('background', 'red');
});
```

Comment: Check all the id's of your grid view records, the example which I have given is for 1 static record.

Comment: All the IDs are static only.

Comment: provide `html` structure for few rows from your grid. So that I can give you exact JS

Comment: I got the jquery to change the color but I am not able to retain the color on page postback.

Comment: So on `check` & `uncheck` are you posting data?

Comment: Not exactly but when some error occurs, I display the message in the alert box which refreshes the page afterwards, resetting the checkboxes colors. So, the checked and the unchecked checkbox is of the same (Red) color.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#checkboxAttendanceStatus').change(function () {
            $("#checkboxAttendanceStatus").css("background", "green");
        });
    });
</script>
```

You can also use `background-color` property of CSS instead of `background`, but `background` takes precedence over `background-color`.

Comment: You can use if-else JS block of @NnN for turning it back to red when unchecking.

Comment: background is not changing the checkbox background.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach in your answer.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $("#GridView1").children("tbody").find("tr").click(function () {
                if ($(this).attr("class") == "highlightedRow")
                {
                    $(this).removeClass("highlightedRow");
                }
                else
                {
                    $(this).addClass("highlightedRow");
                    $(this).siblings("tr.highlightedRow").removeClass("highlightedRow");
                }
            }).mouseover(function () {
                $(this).css("background", "Red");
            }).mouseout(function () {
                $(this).css("background", "");
            });
        });
```

source: https://forums.asp.net/t/1701337.aspx?change+asp+gridview+row+backcolor+in+javascript+

Comment: I don't want this.
I want to change the checkbox color on click of that checkbox.