# Jquery only working for the first entry of the gridview

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

**ASP.NET code**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div id="divStatus" style="width:20px;background:red">
            <input type="checkbox" id="checkboxAttendanceStatus">
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**Jquery**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#checkboxAttendanceStatus').on('change', function () {
            if ($('#checkboxAttendanceStatus').prop('checked'))
                $('#divStatus').css('background', 'green');
            else
                $('#divStatus').css('background', 'red');
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have a checkbox inside a gridview and want to change the color of the same by clicking on it.

**I have used the jquery mentioned above, but it's working only for the first entry of the gridview.**

All the checkbox entries are not reflecting the change accordingly.

Any idea what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change checkbox background color on checkbox check and uncheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785680/change-checkbox-background-color-on-checkbox-check-and-uncheck)

Comment: Please do not post duplicate questions. And you could have found the answer to the problem already if you read the comments of the other question.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. There I asked about the checkbox color change jquery.
But here I am asking about the issue with the gridview as only first entry reflecting the change in color. Also nobody could resolve this issue there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't base your jQuery selector on div id, it will get only the first. Use a class instead and change your jquery code to:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.checkboxClass').on('change', function () {
            if ($(this).prop('checked'))
                $(this).parent().css('background', 'green'); //Will get the parent div to change background color
            else
                $(this).parent().css('background', 'red');
        });
    });
</script>
```

The variable `this` is the checkbox that is triggered by the change event.

Comment: And how do I color all the checkboxes red on page load ?

Comment: If you are always going to load the page with all checkbox in red, you should add the checkbox class to you css and set it red

Comment: That I did but the issue is when some postback occurs on the page, all the checkboxes are red even if some are checked.

Comment: In this case you would have to post you code so we can now you exact contest, so I think it is a different subject. You could create a new question about a postback that is always reseting the checkbox colors and post your code with context there.
If you think my answer was the best suited for your problem, please mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are repeting div id, so jquery always get the first one, try doing your listener by class.

id should be unique in your html.

Comment: But then again, if I will use class for the div, it will change the color of all the checkboxes at once which I don't want.

Comment: you should use this:  this.css('background', 'green');

Answer (score 0):

Ids are repeating n causing only the checkbox of first `ItemTemplate` being invoked and only the first `#divStatus` background being changed