# Input checked change body background colour using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, onsen-ui

I have an input checkbox. I want to change all the body CSS of the HTML (white body-background and black text when unchecked, and black body-background and white text when checked).

HTML:

```
  <input id="nightmode" type="checkbox">Activate night mode
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change checkbox background color on checkbox check and uncheck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48785680/change-checkbox-background-color-on-checkbox-check-and-uncheck)

Comment: It might be good thought instead of specially changing all text to white and the background to white to swap the stylesheet like `main.dark.css` that way if you decide you need to style anything else differently for night mode it would be easier to maintain. There's also probably even better ways, but for simplicity that way might be superior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to check for a change in the checkbox, then set the background color and text color accordingly.

```js
document.getElementById("nightmode").addEventListener("change", function() {
  if (document.getElementById("nightmode").checked == true) {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: black;");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: white;");

  } else {
    document.documentElement.setAttribute("style", "background-color: white;");
    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].setAttribute("style", "color: black;");
  }
});
```

```html
<input id="nightmode" type="checkbox">Activate night mode
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
  survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
  software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>
```

Comment: It work great if I try in a plain HTML, but the problem is I am using Onsen UI framework and it seems it doesn´t work.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
document.querySelector('#chk').onchange = function (e) {
    var check = e.target.checked;
    var backColor = check ? "black" : "white";
    var color = check ? "white" : "black";
    document.querySelector('body').style.background= backColor ;
    document.querySelector('body').style.color= color ;
};
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery for clarity, your checkbox

```
<input id="nightmode" type='checkbox'> Activate night mode
```

triggers the following changes, as you asked:

```
$("#nightmode").change(function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked"))
        $('body').css("background-color", "black").css("color","white"); 
    else
        $('body').css("background-color", "white").css("color","black"); 
});
```

You can try it here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/uJcB7/1550/

Answer (score -1):

Don't go fiddling with the `.style()` on the body element itself; instead define the *styles* in CSS that you want.
Then, if you change your mind sometime in the future, all you have to do is change the CSS instead of going through *all* your javascript and changing every place where you modify the body element's styles.

Normal (day) mode is black on white, and will have no class added: `<body>`. When you switch to night mode it will be white on black, represented by adding the class `<body class="nightmode">`

```js
// Using jQuery ...
//$('#nightmode').change(function() {
//    $('body').toggleClass('nightmode');
//});

// Using plain js ...
document.getElementById('nightmode')
    .addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        document.body.classList.toggle('nightmode')
    });
```

```css
body {
    color: black;
    background-color: white;
}
body.nightmode {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
 <h1>A Heading</h1>
 <div>
 <input id="nightmode" type="checkbox">
 <label for="nightmode">Activate night mode</label>
 </div>
 
 <section>
     <p>A section with a paragraph</p>
 </section>
 <section>
     <p>A second section</p>
 </section>
 <footer>The footer</footer>
</body>
```

Comment: Someone care to explain the downvote? If you think something is wrong with this answer I'd really like to know.